# wordpress image url error when preview theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I preview Wordpress theme, the image doesn't show. there are a lot of 404 errors in the browser console, the image path is wrong as below:

https://6fish.fun/%22https:/6fish.fun/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/neve-web-design-studio-03.1.jpg

the image path is incorrect, how to fix it? is the configuration wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one slash `(/)` in your url it's `https:/` not `https://` so WordPress `esc_url` function might be trying to fix the url thinking it's not a valid `http://` or `https://` url

You can fix the missing slash `(/)` then test if it solves the problem or not.

Comment: I stored the wrong config in the db, recreate db is ok, thanks a lot!